# Unexpected token while trying to render JSX in node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs

I'm trying out server-rendering with React and React Router. I have babel set up to correctly render out jsx on the client side, but the server is giving me trouble. It doesn't seem to recognise my jsx no matter what I do.

My server code looks like this:

```
require("@babel/register")({
presets: ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"]
});

const React = require("react");
const StaticRouter = require("react-router-dom/StaticRouter");
const ReactDOMServer = require("react-dom/server");

app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
 const context = {};
 const app = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
   <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
     <App />
   </StaticRouter>
 );
})
```

I've configured babel in my package.json as:

```
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
  }
```

And have all the dependencies listed.
The error is as follows:

```
 <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Babel cannot transpile the same module where it was registered.

In case Babel is used programmatically as `require("@babel/register")`, there should be entry point that contains the code that is compatible with current Node version, and other modules that will be processed by Babel.

*main.js*

```
require("@babel/register")({
  presets: ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"]
});

require('./app');
```

*app.jsx*

```
const React = require("react");
...
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by: "there should be entry point that contains the code that is compatible with current Node version". What entry point? How do I declare one? Is that extra configuration for babel? If I cant use require("@babel/register) in my server file, where do I put it? It's not reaching my App code, so I'm unsure of your example.

Comment: Okay so I figured it out by looking at another project. I have to create a file that requires babel register and then requires my server file. I have to change my entry point in package.json to be that new file.

Comment: Luke sikuade tell us how you fix it thanks in anticipation

Comment: @hussamsindhu I suppose the OP has something in main.js besides the code that was posted in the answer, and this was a problem for some reason. The suggested solution is to have main.js that contains only `require("@babel/register" ...` and imports other modules like app.jsx with `require`, there may be a need to specify main.js as entry point in package.json