# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in react 18 SSR

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

This is the first time i'm setting up react app SSR from scratch, i'm facinng this below error when run node server.js

```
  <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1245:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:904:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
const { StaticRouter } = require('react-router-dom');
const App = require('./src/App').default;

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const context = {};
  const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
      <App />
    </StaticRouter>
  );

  if (context.url) {
    res.redirect(context.url);
  } else {
    res.render('index', { html });
  }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is listening on port 3000');
});
```

webpack to use the file-loader for any files with the extensions ".png", ".jpg", ".gif", ".svg", or ".html". The file-loader will copy the files to your output directory and generate a unique URL for each file, which you can then use in your JavaScript code.

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const webpackNodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const { FullHumanPostcssPurgecss } = require('@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss');

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/client.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  mode: isProduction ? 'production': 'development',
  optimization: {
    minimize: isProduction,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin(),
      new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
    ],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
       {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|html)$/,
        use: ['file-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          isProduction ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : 'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: [
                  require('tailwindcss'),
                  require('autoprefixer'),
                  ...(isProduction
                    ? [
                        FullHumanPostcssPurgecss({
                          content: ['./src/**/*.js', './views/**/*.ejs'],
                          defaultExtractor: (content) =>
                            content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || [],
                        }),
                      ]
                    : []),
                ],
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
    }),
    ...(isProduction
      ? [
          new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'styles.css',
          }),
        ]
      : []),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },
  externals: [webpackNodeExternals()],
  target: 'node',
};
```

Comment: Maybe this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53895961/11095009

Comment: this didn't work @S.Marx